# CSS transition when position changes due to added / removed DOM elements

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, css-transitions, transition

Is there a way to animate transitions for an element that changes position due to other elements being added / removed in the DOM?

I'm using ionic and angulars `*ngIf` directive to conditionally add/remove elements in the DOM. These I can easily animate via angular animations. Adding/removing these elements will result in another element "changing position" on the page, is there a way to animate this transition?

```
<ion-row>
   <ion-col id="col1" *ngIf="show1" [@animate1]>some-content1</ion-col>
   <ion-col id="col2">some-content2</ion-col>
   <ion-col id="col3" *ngIf="!show1" [@animate3]>some-content3</ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

I either have columns 1 and 2 showing or 2 and 3. Column 2 is always on the page but changes positon from being the right one of 2 columns to being the left one. I want to animate this transition so I can give the impression of the entire page moving left (or right) and bringing the `col1` or `col3` into view respectively.
It basically works but `col2` "jumps" when the animation of 1 and 3 is finished, I want it to be animated as well. Is this possible?

Comment: You could use `state`'s in animations and based on `show1` value trigger them. https://angular.io/guide/animations

Comment: @J.D. that's exactly what I did, but the problem I'm facing is that `col2` does not "actively" change it's position but is just repositioned by the removal of `col1` in the DOM.

Comment: I tihnk you could add state for removing `col1` with some `ease` effect, so col2 wouldn't just jump into that position